# How should questions about 'Canadian football' tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I think there is no tag for 'Canadian football.'

[Canadian football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_football) is different from American football, but they share a lot of things.

Should we create a 'Canadian football' tag, or such questions should be tagged as 'American football?'

Comment: We don't **have** any questions about Canadian football, so the tag cannot exist, because it would not be appropriate for any questions that we do have, and tags are deleted whenever they are not applied to any questions.

Comment: Not *strictly* true, we have one question about the CFL, but close. :)

Comment: Note that we *do* have a [tag](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-rules-football) for Australian Rules Football.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tag: [cfl](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cfl).  That's intended to cover questions about the Canadian football League, which is the highest level of Canadian football.

It would be appropriate to add an additional tag [canadian-football](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canadian-football) if we were to have a question about Canadian football (and not other forms of football) that wasn't related to the CFL.  We don't have one of those; in fact the only question we have that is really *about* the CFL or Canadian football and not just including it as a "here are other leagues related to the question" is [this one](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7010/what-are-the-main-differences-between-regulations-of-the-nfl-and-the-cfl?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C45.1912).

However, tags can't exist without questions, so until that happens there's no reason to add it.

I would say that the tag [american-football](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-football) is sufficient in my opinion for questions that are not about American or Canadian football specifically but can cover either one, given it's the far more popular tag and will surface questions more effectively.